# Send the url of a video, which is played in the android youtube-app, to my kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, manifest

I want to send the url a played video (played in the Android YouTube-Player - App) to an activity of may kotlin app. Can You help me ?  Maybe some Manifest entries necessary or use of a service ?
Thanks for your help !

I made some Manifest -changes without success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `Manifest` file

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
            ...
                <data
                    android:host="youtu.be"
                    android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then receive the url in your activity as follows:

```
intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)?.let {              
    youtubeLink = it
}
```